# ScrollView makes inner GridLayout disappear

Tags: android, scrollview, android-gridlayout

My goal : make some kind of scrollable gallery (for a change). I use a GridLayout with CardView.

I've read many threads, and found out that I needed to insert a ScrollView and put my content-to-be-scrolled in it. The thing is : why does my content-to-be-scrolled disappear when I add the ScrollView around ?

Without the ScrollView, it's perfectly displayed (except that, consequently, everything is displayed on the same "page", and so, is too small).

Could you explain me why it doesn't work ?

Thanks a lot :)

This is my xml code :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".RecipeActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:rowCount="3"
            android:columnCount="2">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:onClick="seeRecipe">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:src="@drawable/chocolatine"/>

                    <!-- random TextView -->

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <!-- 15 more android.support.v7.widget.CardView -->

        </GridLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My java code is empty, except for the necessary stuff (onCreate...).

Comment: If you want scrolling, a RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager is probably a cleaner and easier option. It even has scrolling built in.

Answer (score 0):

Trimming things way down, I see this:

> ```
> <GridLayout
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="0dp"
>     android:layout_weight="8"
> ```

The parent tag of this GridLayout is a `<ScrollView>`, and ScrollViews **do not** support the concept of layout weights. This means that you have simply defined your `GridLayout` to have a height of zero, which is why it no longer displays.

It seems likely to me that you could solve this by deleting the `layout_weight` attribute and setting the height to be `wrap_content`.